# Use implicits to infer an unknown type

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, type-inference, implicit

I am trying to get the compiler to infer some type based on 2 other type parameters that are known. here's the example:

```scala
trait ReturnCount
trait ReturnsMany extends ReturnCount
trait ReturnsOne extends ReturnCount

class Query[R <: ReturnCount]{
    def join[R2 <: ReturnCount,R3 <: ReturnCount](q: Query[R2]): Query[R3]
}
```

As you can see here I want to be able to join two read queries (the details of composition for which is irrelevant). the resulting new query has to be a query that either `ReturnsOne` or `ReturnsMany` results. the rule of resolution is also pretty simple: Only if both queries `ReturnsOne` then the joined query also `ReturnsOne` in all other cases it `ReturnsMany`.

So:

```scala
val q1 = new Query[ReturnsOne]
val q2 = new Query[ReturnsMany]
val q3 = q1 join q2 //I don't want to have 
                    //to specify R3 because compiler should do it for me...
```

How can I hope to achieve this?

Comment: If ```R``` is of type ```ReturnsOne``` then I need ```R2``` to know how many results the query returns. If R was of type ```ReturnsMany``` then you'd be right it wouldn't make any difference as it would be ```ReturnsMany``` anyway

Comment: Why is the number of results determined by `R2` and not `R`? What is the general use of `R` here?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It's determined by R3 actually and R3 needs both R and R2 to decide. I'm looking for that implicit argument that resolves R3 using R and R2 to be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would do such a thing for the case where those 3 traits are sealed. If they are open to extension it will probably become more complicated.

It boils down to the following. You have a trait `Fancy` with two input types `A` and `B`, and one output type `Out`. You define the implicit instances such that in the case where `A` and `B` are both `ReturnsOne`, `Out` will be `ReturnsOne`. In all other cases you fall back to a default case with a lower priority (because otherwise you will get ambiguity errors) where `Out` always is `ReturnsMany`.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait ReturnCount
sealed trait ReturnsMany extends ReturnCount
sealed trait ReturnsOne extends ReturnCount

sealed trait Fancy[A, B] {
  type Out <: ReturnCount
}

object Fancy extends LowerPriority {
  type Aux[A,B,Out1 <: ReturnCount] = Fancy[A,B] { type Out = Out1 }

  implicit def returnsOne: Fancy.Aux[ReturnsOne,ReturnsOne,ReturnsOne] = 
    new Fancy[ReturnsOne,ReturnsOne] { type Out = ReturnsOne }
}

trait LowerPriority {
  implicit def returnsMany[A,B]: Fancy.Aux[A,B,ReturnsMany] = 
    new Fancy[A,B] { type Out = ReturnsMany }
}

class Query[R <: ReturnCount] { 
  def join[R2 <: ReturnCount](q: Query[R2])(implicit fancy: Fancy[R,R2]): Query[fancy.Out] = ??? 
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait ReturnCount
defined trait ReturnsMany
defined trait ReturnsOne
defined trait Fancy
defined object Fancy
defined trait LowerPriority
defined class Query

scala> :type new Query[ReturnsOne].join(new Query[ReturnsOne])
Query[ReturnsOne]

scala> :type new Query[ReturnsOne].join(new Query[ReturnsMany])
Query[ReturnsMany]

scala> :type new Query[ReturnsMany].join(new Query[ReturnsMany])
Query[ReturnsMany]

scala> :type new Query[ReturnsMany].join(new Query[ReturnsOne])
Query[ReturnsMany]
```

In a real scenario your `Fancy` will probably also need a `join` method which will contain the actual implementations that your `Query#join` method delegates to:

```
class Query[R <: ReturnCount] { 
  def join[R2 <: ReturnCount](q: Query[R2])(implicit fancy: Fancy[R,R2]): Query[fancy.Out] =
    fancy.join(this, q)
}
```

[This blog](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/ImplicitDesignPatternsinScala.html#type-driving-implicits) might be a good starting point to learn more about such patterns.